# Is there a way we can use lucene to discover the relevancy of word based on search query

Tags: solr, lucene, machine-learning, autosuggest

All:

I wonder if there is any way that we can use lucene to do search keyword relevancy discovering based on search history?

For example:

The code can read in user search string, parse it, extract the keyword and find out which words have most possibility to come together when search.

When I try Solr, I found that the lucene has a lot of text analysis feature, that is why I am wondering if there is any way we can use it and combine with other machine learning libs(if necessary) to achieve my goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

### Yes.

It should work. Simply treat every keyword as a document and then use [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html) feature of lucene, which constructs a lucene query on the fly based on terms within the raw query. The lucenue query is then used to find other similar documents (keywords) in the index.

```
MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader); // Pass the index reader
mlt.setFieldNames(new String[] {"keywords"}); // specify the field for similarity

Query query = mlt.like(docID); // Pass the doc id 
TopDocs similarDocs = searcher.search(query, 20); // Use the searcher
if (similarDocs.totalHits == 0)
    // Do handling
}
```

Suppose in your indexed keywords, you have such keywords as

```
iphone 6
apple iphone
iphone on sale
apple and fruit
apple and pear
```

when you launch a query with "iphone", I am sure you will find the first three keywords above as "most similar" due to the full term match of "iphone".

### No.

The **default** similarity function in lucene never understands that iphone is relevant to Apple Inc, thus iphone is relevant to "apple store". If your raw query is just "apple store", an ideal search result within your current keywords would be as follows (ordered by relevancy from high to low):

```
apple iphone
iphone 6
iphone on sale
```

unfortunately, you will get below results:

```
apple iphone
apple and fruit
apple and pear
```

The first one is great however the other two are totally unrelated. To  get the **real** relevancy discovery (using the **semantic**) , you need more work to do [topic modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model). If you happen to have a great way (e.g., a pre-trained [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) model or [wordvec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) ) to pre-process each keyword and produce a list of topic ids, you can store those topic ids in a separate field with each keyword document. Something like below:

```
[apple iphone]      ->  topic_iphone:1.0, topic_apple_inc:0.8
[apple and fruit]   ->  topic_apple_fruit:1.0
[apple and pear]    ->  topic_apple_fruit:0.99, topic_pear_fruit:0.98
```

where each keyword is also mapped to a few topic ids with weight value.

At query time, you should run the same topic modeling tool to generate topic ids for the raw query together with its terms. For example,

```
[apple store]       ->  topic_apple_inc:0.75, topic_shopping_store:0.6
```

Now you should combine the two fields (keyword and topic) to compute the overall similarity.

Comment: Just casually informing myself about lucene and solr in general you have helped me a lot by giving me new topics to google, thanks!